# One of my dual monitors won't work after waking up from sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, sleep

Almost every time I wake my computer from sleep after more than approximate 40 minutes, my left monitor stops working.  Blue and black vertical lines appear on the screen.

The weird thing is that the computer still recognizes that the monitor is plugged in.  Both monitors are plugged in using DVI cables.  I have replaced the cable for the left monitor but this problem still happens.

Restarting seems to restore both monitors to working condition, but it's kind of annoying to do every time I leave my computer for a little bit of time.  I know it's not a big deal but I would like to figure out why my monitor is doing this.

Here's a photo of my monitors, with the left monitor not working properly:
[image]

Here's screenshot of both monitors;
the computer still recognizes the left monitor:
[image]

Comment: You really need to decide if this is a computer problem or a monitor problem. What happens if you switch the DVI cables around when this occurs? Do the blue lines move or stay on the same monitor, or go away all together - how about after 40 min inactivity? Have you tried removing power from the affected monitor and restoring it while the problem is occurring?

Comment: What is your graphics card?  Do you have correct/updated drivers?